# How should I evaluate a good fit amongst Mamp, Xampp, Apache or Wamp for my project?

Tags: php, apache, xampp, wamp, mamp

I'm willing to start a web development project and I have none or little experience with these products.

How do you think I could evaluate these webservers for local development use with PHP and MySql?

I feel sort of confused and can't make a final decision for one of them.

Comment: This is largely Opinion based.   That said personally I use something called Uniserver.  I like it because it requires no installation and can be ran from a flash drive, or just copied from one computer to another.  I wouldn't use it as a production server though.  It also has modules that let you switch what version of PHP you are using right though the interface, and a few other nice things.

Comment: My voate is Docker, ha! and also to close this question.

Comment: he objetive is for host a web and be accesible by router

Comment: This question seems opinion based. Yes. But most questions that seem opinion based can be re-worked to think a level up of abstraction. I believe this helps newcomers to think of methods that fit well for their problem instead of products that stick well to opinions. It's just a matter of perspective.

Answer (score 2):

Your question can be answered with any given array of webserver, and that way we go a level up of abstraction to see the "big picture" and avoid opinion-based choice among *brands*, just *product brands*.

---

The important thing is not **which** of them *should you use*, but 
***what*** are the important aspects to consider in order to make a reasonable choice that fits well **for you**.

Making a comprehensive evaluation of features amongst a variety of products is not an easy task, it has a methodology in terms of *Software Engineering* and *IT Management* and despite all formal steps, in the end *it's up to you* and your team the actual *whys* for making *that choice*.

As a rule of thumb, get to know that it's a common practice to have many stages of your application: *local*, *testing*, *user acceptance*, *production*. These stages may vary, but it will be common to see at least local and production. So consider trying to have the same webserver that will be used in production (or at least the next stage), in order to reduce as much as possible the friction of deploying forward to production environment.

Also consider using a webserver that is easy for you or your team to setup, specially taking into account that your question itself reveals the need of ease of use (at least for the first steps).

Finally, consider making your research, build a (or search Internet) comparison table to visualize their features as pros and cons related to the needs of your project.

If you are willing to start learning web development and you have no rush to get into production, just grab the one that appeals you the most as an easy start, and consider giving the other options a try as that will provide you with enough experience as to get an accurate idea of what could be a better fit for future projects.

Comment: thoughtful answer : i would add the necessity to consider multiple environments (dev, staging, prod) and the need to avoid deployment friction during the complete build promotion cycle.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are a newbie, if your computer is mac, use Mamp, otherwise use Wamp.

Comment: not even worth a downvote !  just play nice please, and this is `comment material` rather than an answer - less the name calling.